# How can i open system file explorer in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, iphone, cordova

I want to open system file explorer in phone-gap to open files of specific folder ,so please help me to implement this concept.

Thanks.

Comment: show your tried code..

Comment: hello Sridhar thanks for reply,I don't have tried any code ,i'm new to phonegap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya you can on android [Mobile File Explorer with PhoneGap/Cordova](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Mobile-File-Explorer-with-PhoneGap-Cordova-and-jQuery-Mobile-Part-1/74926)

OR

This is native code to file chooser. Try this and create plugin for that

```
    Intent  i= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    i.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(i,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);



        @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode){
        case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){

                     Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

                        cursor.close();
                        System.out.println("picturePath +"+ picturePath );  //path of sdcard

                        textFile.setText(picturePath);

            }

            break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for reply Amit, i already have this code ,but i want to open default system file explorer.

Comment: Do you have idea about plugin developement

Comment: I'm new to phonegap ,i don't have any idea to develop any plugin